# Client continuously asking for new logo concepts and he is not sure of what he wants. How do I deal with him?

Tags: payment-terms, difficult-client, project-management

I have a new client for whom I am designing a vector logo. I provide 3 concepts and he is supposed to choose one of them based on which I will be making unlimited revisions.
Unfortunately, even though I have provided him with 13 unique logo concepts for the logo already, he is still asking me for a logo design that looks "more modern". I do not understand what he means by "more modern" and so, I asked him to give me some examples. However, he is not giving me references- like some logo designs that he likes, despite me asking him to provide me with some references because I am not sure what he wants exactly.

I collected feedback from other users for the logo concepts that I have already made. Most of them like the logos and find them creative and unique. However, the client may have something else in mind but he is not sharing some examples or references. Due to this, I am unable to figure out what kind of logo is he exactly looking for.

I have already collected the payment for the logo design. But I am having to work too much in creating fresh concepts. And the client is not supporting me with some logo design examples or references/inspirations that he likes.

How do I deal with my client in this situation? Also, if the client is not satisfied with the designs, then will it be a good idea to refund him the amount, or shall I make it non-refundable considering the enormous amount of time and efforts I have already invested in creating so many concepts?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've done the work, a refund is not warranted in my opinion. It would be one thing if you failed to provide services. However, from what you've written, you have provided services.

---

Imagine you go to a restaurant and order a meal and pay for it up front. The chef cooks the meal and a server delivers it... you tell the server "Well, I need it to be more modern." So the chef cooks a *second meal*, server delivers it, you don't like it, chef cooks a third meal.. how long do you think this would be allowed to continue without additional charges?

---

How to get a handle on things (this is a bit general and broad without seeing artwork)...

**Limit Choices** and **ask pointed questions**.

- Do you like the X in this version or in this version?
  <sup>(NOT which one do you like?)</sup>
- Do you prefer the red or the blue?
  <sup>(NOT which colors do you prefer?)</sup>
- Do you like the square or the circle?
  <sup>(NOT which version would you prefer?)</sup>
- Do you like 'this' font or 'this' font?
  <sup>(NOT which typeface do you like?)</sup>

Generally if you can limit choices to A and B, you will get better responses and have a more solid sense of direction. You can even find brands you *think* the client may like and ask about those.. do you think logoX is more modern than logoY?

Ultimately though, some clients just have difficulty expressing anything conceptual. They are the *"I'll know it when I see it"* type of clients which can be frustrating. At times this means you need to have a conversation with them to *remind* them of your contractual obligations.

Merely a **suggestion**....

> Hi Client,
>
> I'm a bit concerned about how this development process is unfolding. We agreed I would create 3 unique concepts, which you'd select from, and then I would finalize. To date, I've created X concepts. This is well above what we agreed upon.
>
> I sincerely want to provide you with a workable logo you are proud of and happy to display. My concern is that we seemingly haven't even reached the first stage of approval - i.e. approval of concept. We need to nail this down as soon as possible. I can't continue creating new concepts ad nausium based upon the agreed upon fees. In addition, I have other commitments and need to move on from this project.
>
> Please review the concepts created to date :[add link]: and let me know which you feel is closest to completion. I'm happy to make edits to any of these existing concepts in order to finalize it, but continually creating new concepts is not possible without further budget considerations.
>
> Thanks for your understanding

Answer (score 1):

It kind of depends what you were suppose to do. I have been in "your customer's shoes" when it comes to buy graphical materials. If I know what I wanted, I could just have it made by myself or if I knew something I like, I would have a "template" to follow and do it by myself.

For me there were many things that were important and that was of course that they were able to deliver the graphical, but the most important for me was they knew what would be attractive to my audience. I gave them a profile of them (age, sex, education, typical work and location/country)

They had no idea how to target that audience and even they have done nice design. For example, a restaurant in Asia, it's far away from the same design that looks appealing to my audience and the context it was needed for. In the end, I had to cancel, even though they did good graphical work, they did not deliver what i needed.

So make sure you understand what you are suppose to deliver to your customer and not only some "creative work".

Comment: I agree. Maybe it is best to create a "persona" profile based on my client's requirements and collect some references or examples of logos that they like. Then I would have a better idea of the design type that my client is looking for.

Comment: And it is important for the client to ask for examples of prior work. If I am looking at a graphics designer's portfolio and don't see anything I like, it is best to look for a different designer. On the designer's side, it can help to show the portfolio and ask if the prospect likes anything they see. Unfortunately, there are clients who will glance at a portfolio, say they like it all, but then not like anything provided.

Answer (score 0):

1. Before works start your collect data from all requirement forms filled
2. clearly understood clients requirements and make more interactions with them
3. give more mokeups

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing or being able to know what the client wants is a costly endeavor. This client should learn the lesson. I.e. reflect it in your billings.